# Swift: How to show sample code as a text or a text field in my app?

Tags: ios, swift, text, share, sample

Is it possible to get the multiline code sample as a text with the possibility to share it later?
Let say I have a sample code:

```
    let a = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ball01")
    a.position = CGPoint(x: width*0.5, y: height*0.5)
    a.size = CGSize(width: width*0.1, height: width*0.1)
    a.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: a.frame.width*0.5)
```

Is it possible to share it as a multiline text? I found some discussions about html, but nothing about the "normal" swift code. Thank you.

Here is a desired sample which could be shared as a Note or smth like that:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find simple and elegant solution here: [How to work with Multi-Line String Literals in Swift](https://www.agnosticdev.com/content/how-work-multi-line-string-literals-swift):

```
let multilineString: """
      let a = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ball01")
      a.position = CGPoint(x: width*0.5, y: height*0.5)
      a.size = CGSize(width: width*0.1, height: width*0.1)
      a.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: a.frame.width*0.5)
      """

      label.text = multilineString
      label.numberOfLines = 0
```